# Create Remote Select2 v4 Option with custom parameters

Tags: jquery-select2-4

here is the problem, I can create the custom option as specify on documentation like this:

```
var option = new Option("my custom option", "myid", true, true);
$('select[name="myselect"]').append(option).trigger('change');

// manually trigger the `select2:select` event
$('select[name="myselect"]').trigger({
    type: 'select2:select',
    params: {
        data: {
            id: "myid",
            text: "my custom option",
            customparam: {
                hello: "I'm here"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So, this creates the option normally and shows on select2 as selected as expected, this also trigger the select2:select event and I can read the extra parameter when this event is trigger, but here comes the problem, I can NOT access the extra parameter by doing this:

```
$('select[name="myselect"]').select2('data')[0].customparam
```

it's like the custom parameter is not attached to the element and it was only pass to the events.

Answer (score 1):

for all who try to find an solution to add the custom parameters back on remote select2, here is what I did and worked perfectly:

```
$('select[name="yourfieldname"]')
  .append(new Option(`${doc.n}`, doc._id, true, true))
  .select2('data')[0].customparam = doc.i;
```

then just when you need call:

```
$('select[name="yourfieldname"]').select2('data')[0].customparam
```

Answer (score 1):

The method described by @rafaelrglima's works for me, but I prefer the method below, which was gleaned from dejan9393's answer in [Github issue 2830](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830#issuecomment-291694282):

```
var dataAdapter = $('select[name="myselect"]').data('select2').dataAdapter;
dataAdapter.addOptions(dataAdapter.convertToOptions([{
     id: "myid",
     text: "mycustomoption",
     customparam: "hello"
}]));
```

I prefer this way because I don't have to have one step for adding "id" and "text" and separate step for adding custom parameters. Also [convertToOptions](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/develop/src/js/select2/data/array.js) takes an array, so you have a convenient way to add multiple options in one step.